# Quero fechar um arquivo em python e depois abri-lo de novo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Não liguem pro nome das variáveis. Quando o programa vai a tentar abrir o arquivo depois de fechado, não abre.

```
from time import strftime
n = 2
cl = 2
abrir_arquivo = open("C:/Users/lucas/Documents/Documento.rtf", 'w')
while(1):
    m = 2**n - 1
    v = 1
    simples =  int(m / 2 + 1)
    o = 0
    h = strftime('%D %H:%M:%S')
    for c in range(0, simples):
        if m % v == 0:
            o = o + 1
        v = v + 1
        if o == 3:
            break
    if o < 3:
        print('Esse número mercene é primo: %i. Ele é o M%i. Ele foi elevado à %i.'%(m,cl, n))
        print(strftime('%D:%H:%M:%S'),'   ', h)
        **abrir_arquivo
        abrir_arquivo.write('Esse número mercene é primo: %i. Ele é o M%i. Ele foi elevado à %i.'%(m,cl, n))
        abrir_arquivo.close()**
        cl = cl + 1
        n = n + 1
```

Comment: Acho que faltou o seu código na pergunta, mas por que você quer fechar e depois abrir o mesmo arquivo?

Comment: É porque eu quero que quando eu feche o programa ele salve o que já foi processado

Comment: Eu ainda vou fazer modificações no código para que ele pegue o dado que foi salvo no arquivo e continue processando daquele ponto

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir um arquivo e inserir um conteúdo no fim do conteúdo já existente, você deve passar a flag **a+**(append) no **open()**, ao invés da flag **w**, que apenas abre o arquivo para escrita.

Exemplo:

```
file = open('arquivo.txt', 'a')
file.write('Hello World!')
file.close()
```

O texto **Hello World!** é inserido no fim do **arquivo.txt**, e não sobrescreve o conteúdo já existente.

Answer (score 0):

Nao entendo a eficiência do que voce esta fazendo, mas voce pode declarar uma função pra isso

```
def abre_arquivo():
    arquivo = open("C:/Users/lucas/Documents/Documento.rtf", 'w')
```

E chamar ela quando precisar gravar alguma coisa.

```
if o < 3:
    print('Esse número mercene é primo: %i. Ele é o M%i. Ele foi elevado à %i.'%(m,cl, n))
    print(strftime('%D:%H:%M:%S'),'   ', h)
    abre_arquivo()
    arquivo.write('Esse número mercene é primo: %i. Ele é o M%i. Ele foi elevado à %i.'%(m,cl, n))
    arquivo.close()
```

O único problema, é que voce vai ter que estruturar diferente o teu programa da maneira mais *padrao*

A unica observação que eu queria fazer pra voce, é que no momento que o Python recebe o `write` ele grava a linha no arquivo de texto. Então tecnicamente falando, voce só esta complicando uma coisa simples :/